# How to iterate recursively over Protobuf Python message to find all field

Tags: python, iteration, field, protocol-buffers, message

This is how I did it, is there a native way to find all fields inside nested protobuf messages;

This is for a two layer nested message

```py
for field in mes2.DESCRIPTOR.fields:
  if 'fields' in dir(field.message_type):
    for sub_field in field.message_type.fields:
      print(sub_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
message = [1, 7, {3: "tsdf", "y": (4, 7)}, [4, 8, 'w']]

def print_fields(message):
    if type(message) not in (list, tuple, dict, set):
        return
    for i in message:
        if type(i) in (list, tuple, dict, set):
            print_fields(i)
        else:
            print(i)

# -> 1, 7, 3, 'y', 4, 8, 'w'
```

Comment: So that would be a valid answer, but is there something even simplier for Google's Protobuf Message; ie . message.GetAllField()